# Wpf Zoombox with ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, zooming

I'm using WPF Toolkit `Zoombox` control and I am wondering if there's a way to wrap the `Zoombox` control inside a simple `ScrollViewer`.

`Zoombox` control doesn't seem to implement that functionality.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It now has a [IsUsingScrollBars](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfToolkit/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Zoombox.Zoombox~IsUsingScrollBars.html) property :)